# Is the name ラーメンバー appropriate for this situation?

Tags: english-to-japanese

I'm drawing an izakaya where a person is eating ramen and having a beer. I was thinking 'ラーメンバー' would be a fitting name for the sign in front. I want to know if this is strange in any way as I don't want to make the drawing culturally ignorant.

The sign would probably be written vertically like this:

ラ

l

メ

ン

バ

l

Comment: Sadly, per the site rules, we do not do translation checking here without evidence of prior effort.

Comment: I am a beginner in Japanese and I understand the rules but my prior effort was shown in the post. My question actually has more to do with whether or not the name itself is appropriate for the situation.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: FYI There was(?) a snack called [らーめんばあ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDDTyjfa4dc)

Comment: ラーメンバー does exist in reality, but ラーメンバー signals you are very confident of the lineup and the quality of alcohol. If you're willing to prepare 10 brands of beer, 20 brands of sake and so on, ラーメンバー should be fine. Still, バー is usually associated with western atmosphere as shown in the picture below. If you are thinking of Japanese-style *izakaya*, ラーメン居酒屋 may be safer.

Comment: @user51438 There are many ○○バーs out there with casual atmosphere; here's a [焼肉バー](http://www.san-tama.jp/) which looks nothing like the stereotypical picture pasted below. Nothing wrong with that, it's a matter of marketing/branding. But the answer and comments here also have a valid point. If you wish to follow their advice and avoid the word バー, you may also want to check out the word バル as in 麺バル. This helps reduce the impression of what looks like that "western bar", but raises expectation for the quality of food. I hope you come up with a good sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your spelling is perfectly correct. Nice.

> ラーメンバー

But I think "ラーメン店" or "ラーメン〇〇（something name）" would be suitable name fot the sign.

Because

> バー

is look like this:

[image: None]

bar is little formal naturaly.

Comment: Thank you. I should have specified that the establishment I'm drawing is more like an informal izakaya that serves ramen. What do you think would be most appropriate for the name?

Comment: In that case, you can use a name like  〇〇ラーメン (where the "〇〇" is a name that describes the izakaya) or ラーメン〇〇.
If the main menu of the izakaya is not ramen, but other items are on the main menu and ramen is served among them, the name can be generally written with[this](https://www.google.com/maps/search/%E5%B1%85%E9%85%92%E5%B1%8B/@39.0075721,-77.2453297,11z/data=!3m1!4b1)
  I chose this place by google map, but I don't know which place is this.

Comment: What's the nuance between 店 and 屋?